# jqueryui datepicker time and day constraint

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a requirement where I need to show all the coming Fridays of the month but with some rules:

1. To show the coming ones and not the previous Fridays.
2. Monday until Wednesday at 10 am, show Friday in current week
3. After Wednesday 10:01 am until Sunday, show Friday next week

What I did so far shows covers the first point perfectly alright, but I am really clueless how to proceed ahead with the other two points.

Here is what I did:

```
       var minimumDate = dateParser(MyProfile.nextDistDate);
       var parsedMinimumDate = new Date();
       console.log(" parsedMinimumDate : "+parsedMinimumDate);
        $("#delivery_from_date").datepicker({
          defaultDate : "+1w",
          dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
          regional: 'en',
          changeMonth: true,
          minDate: minimumDate,
          firstDay: 1,
          beforeShowDay: function(date) {
            return [date.getDay() == 5];
          }
        });
```

minimumDate is a variable which consists of a date, which is by default the coming Friday.

Any advices please?

Comment: What is `MyProfile.nextDistDate`?

Comment: @Danny Thats a timestamp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the day of the week, and if it's a wednesday check if it's over 10am as well, and set the minimum date to either today or one week ahead depending on what day it is :

```
var date = new Date();
var day  = date.getDay();
var min  = 0;

if (day >= 3) { // wednesday -> saturday 23:59
    if (day == 3) { // it's a wednesday
        if (date.getHours() > 10) { // it's over 10 am
            min = '+1w';
        }
    }else{ // it's thursday -> sunday
        min = '+1w';
    }
}

$("#delivery_from_date").datepicker({
    defaultDate   : "+1w",
    dateFormat    : "dd/mm/yy",
    regional      : 'en',
    changeMonth   : true,
    minDate       : min,
    firstDay      : 1,
    beforeShowDay : function (date) {
        return [date.getDay() == 5];
    }
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/UrDL5/1/)

Comment: Perfect! I made few modifications, like instead of checking greater then 10 I am checking for >=. It works like charm.

Answer (score 1):

You could just try this:

```
var minimumDate = dateParser(MyProfile.nextDistDate);
var today= new Date();

if(today.getDay() >= 3 && today.getHours() >= 10){
    minimumDate.setDate(minimumDate.getDate()+7);
}
```

The code checks if today is > wednesday & > 10hr ... if it is, than it adds 7 days to the minimum date => next week